# Nodejs behaviour

Tags: node.js, mongodb, data-modeling

I have been working on nodeJS + MongoDB, using the Express and Mongoose frameworks for a few months, and I wanted to ask you guys what is really happening in a situation such as the following:

```
Model1.find({}, function (err, elems) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR');
    } else {
        elems.forEach(function (el) {
            Model2.find({[QUERY RELATED WITH FIELDS IN 'el']}, function (err, elems2) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('ERROR');
                } else {
                    //DO STAFF.
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

My best guess is that there's a main thread looping over elems, and then different threads attending each query over Model2, but I'm not really sure.

Is that correct? And also, is this a good solution? And if not, how would you code in a situation such as this, where you need the information in each of the elements you get from Model1 to get elements from Model2, and perform the actual functionality you are looking for?

I know I could elaborate a more complex query where I could get all the elements each of the 'el' in elems would yield, but I¡d rather not do that, because in that case i would be worried about the memory expense.

Also, I've been thinking about changing the data model, but I've gone over it and I'm confident it is well thought, and I don't think that's the best solution for my aplication.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJS is a single threaded environment and it works asynchronously for blocking function calls such as network requests in your case. So there is only one thread and your query results will be called asynchronously so that nothing will be blocked due to intensive network operation.

In your scenario if the first query returns quite a lot of records such as 100000 thousands you may exhaust your mongo server in your loop as you will query your server as many as the result of first query instantly. This will happen because node won't stop for receiving the results of each query as it works asynchronously.

So usually manually throttling the requests to network operations is a good practice. This is not trivial when working on asynchronous environment. One way to do is to use recursive function call. Basically you split your tasks into groups and do each group in batch, once you are done with one batch you start with your next group.

Here is a simple example on how to do it, I have used promises instead of callback functions, [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) is a promise library that is very useful for handling promises:

```
var rows = [...]; // array of many

function handleRecursively(startIndex, batchSize){
 var promises = [];
 for(i = 0; i < batchSize && i + batchSize < rows.length; i++){
   var theRow = rows[startIndex + i];
   promises.push(doAsynchronousJobWithTheRow(theRow));
 }
 //you wait until you handle all tasks in this iteration
 Q.all(promises).then(function(){
   startIndex += batchSize;
   if(startIndex < rows.length){ // if there is still task to do continue with next batch
handleRecursively(startIndex, batchSize);    }
 })
}

handleRecursively(0, 1000);
```

Comment: I wouldn't use this example, because `promise.all` doesn't guarantee to settle all the promises, based on a race condition, which isn't acceptable within a database connection. You have to guarantee to settle all the promises in this instance, or else your code will be failing under heavy load when one of the promises within `promise.all` suddenly settles outside of the current database connection. I have had lots of experience with this kind of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution :

```
Model1.find({}, function (err, elems) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR');
    } else {
        loopAllElements(0,elems);
    }
});
function loopAllElements(startIndex,elems){
    if (startIndex==elems.length) {
        return "success"; 
    }else{
            Model2.find({[QUERY RELATED WITH FIELDS IN elems[startIndex] ]}, function (err, elems2) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('ERROR');
                    return "error"; 
                } else {
                    //DO STAFF.
                    loopAllElements(startIndex+1, elems);  
                }
            });
    }
}
```